# dynamic translation with I18Next and Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia, i18next

I have an aurelia app that I am integrating I18Next with, I have the Aurelia integration working and it was all going smoothly, until I came upon our menu. For normal translations we are just using the html attributes like so...

```
<a href="somelink" i18n="link1">Link 1</a>
```

then in translation.json files you have

```
{
  link1: "some translation here"
}
```

and that works great, it translates perfectly. The problem I can't figure out is how to handle dynamic stuff, like for example our menu. We are doing a repeat.for to make the menu, but how do I tell I18Next what key to use from the translations.json file? Here is a simplified example of what I mean.

```
<li repeat.for="item of router.navigation">
  <a href.bind="item.href" class="${item.isActive? 'is_active' : ''}>
    ${item.title}
  </a>
</li>
```

Given the above layout, how can you possibly tell I18Next what keys to use for translation, since it is done in  a loop. I have tried a few things, but all have failed. I am really stuck here, I need to get this to translate using the translation.json files, but I have no idea how to tell it what key to use for the translation, is it "home", "about", "contact", ...? Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try binding it like this (based on your first example): `<a i18n.bind="item.title">`

Comment: I thought about that, but since there is a translation file, the "item.title" wouldn't be translated, I need the item.title to be the part that gets translated. Like in the link example, I need to point to a key in the translation.json file. I am doing binding on other items like a username, which wouldn't need to be translated.

Comment: If you let the value of `item.title` be a key in your translations file, and then bind on it like in the comment above, it should work. I have a similar setup myself, where I use `t.bind="messageKey"` (t being the equivalent of your `i18n` attribute

Comment: That makes sense, so I would have something like <a i18n="navigation.${item.title}">${item.title}</a> and that would then link to the translation key navigation.[whatever the title is], which I could then translate. Nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like any other attribute, you can bind to your i18n attribute with aurelia. Using the following syntax:

```
<a i18n.bind="'navigation.' + item.title"></a>
```

I18n will look for a key in your resources file with the name `navigation.[item.title]`, so if the `item.title` variable equals to "home", it will look for a key named `navigation.home`.